# Create ASP.NET ReportViewer in a child control in ASP.NET; Document Map button breaks

Tags: asp.net, controls, reportviewer2008

We are having a strange issue with the Visual Studio 2008 ReportViewer control.  Specifically, when we have a child control on a page, and the child control itself hosts a report viewer, and the report has a document map, the postback on the show/hide document map button seems to be lost, so the document map never disappears.  I played with IPostBackEventHandler and didn't seem to get anywhere; the ReportViewer itself implements that interface so I didn't think I cared.  Anyway, here's the code:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ReportViewerDocumentMapButtonStrippedExample._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="div">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;

namespace ReportViewerDocumentMapButtonStrippedExample {
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls() {
            base.CreateChildControls();
            FindControl("div").Controls.Add(new rvControl());
        }
    }
}
```

rvControl.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

namespace ReportViewerDocumentMapButtonStrippedExample {
    public class rvControl : HtmlGenericControl {

        protected override void CreateChildControls() {
            base.CreateChildControls();
            var rvMain = new ReportViewer {
                EnableViewState = true,
                ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote,
                ShowRefreshButton = false,
                AsyncRendering = true,
                Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage),
                Height = new Unit(2000, UnitType.Pixel),
                ShowCredentialPrompts = false,
                ID = "viewer",
            };
            rvMain.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/some/report/name";
            Controls.Add(rvMain);
        }

    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: Just to follow up on this question, we talked with Microsoft about this.  For 2008, it's unlikely anything will change, unless a case is opened and pushed.  For 2010, they are looking at this (the failure is worse in that case - no report is visible due to infinite postbacks) and can readily reproduce the failure mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft found the answer for us.  Basically, it was some confusion in ReportViewer control and the control lifecycle.  The fix is a simple addition to the custom control:

```
public override System.Web.UI.ControlCollection Controls {
    get {
        this.EnsureChildControls();
        return base.Controls;
    }
}
```